# Remove web properties by api (Google Analytics)

Tags: google-analytics

I need to remove web properties by api in GA. Here i read about beta for developers and requested access.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties

Answer was:

**Analytics Writes Whitelist for project number xxxxx has been approved.**

But a dont understand how to remove web properties. It will be method like management_webproperties->delete where i can read about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the API for Web Properties does not support the `delete` method [[reference]](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties#methods)

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, there are some potential workarounds:

- Rename the property to something like "z (Archived) Property Name" so that it appears at the bottom of the list of properties for a user.
- Delete all views under a property. The property will still exist, but will be "empty".

Comment: Information from offical page:

"Write operations in the Management API (e.g. create, update, delete, patch) for Web Property, View (Profile), and Goal resources are currently available as a developer preview in limited beta"

Comment: @DanialRobessarShevchuk yes, I saw that too. But it looks like the `delete` method is only available for Views.